# Possible to connect Site VPN to Bluemix Spark Service?

Tags: containers, ibm-cloud, message-hub

**Background:**

- I have a DB cluster hosted in Softlayer
- I utilize No Bluemix 'container' services
- I utilize Spark and MessageHub Services in Bluemix

**Question**

**- Please explain how I can securely connect the bluemix spark service to my DB cluster through a Site VPN connection?**
 - The UI for the Bluemix VPN indicates I have to specify a container or container group to connect - but how does that correspond to Spark/MessageHub Services? To my knowledge those are shared services, not containers or container groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VPNaaS on Bluemix currently supports services/applications running on Bluemix docker-containers.

Comment: Even to their underlying infrastructure - softlayer? That...is a disappointment.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this out:-

If you have accessible JDBC connection to your database(since i am not sure which database you are accessing).

Depending on your database driver, you can enable ssl connection on the jdbc url.

jdbc://${env.hostname}:10000/default;ssl=true;sslTrustStore=./truststore.jks;trustStorePassword=mypassword;

Follow the guide from this post to import certificates if needed.
http://stackoverflow.duapp.com/questions/37109302/how-to-connect-to-remote-hive-running-on-biginsights-on-cloud-from-a-spark-as-a/37121741

Change the url with your database url(ex. postgres below)
df = sqlContext.load(source="jdbc",\
                 url="jdbc:postgresql://[publichost]:[port]/databasename",\
                 dbtable="[tablename]")

Thanks,
Charles.